# One way binding in directive picking up second value

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive like this

```
app.directive('isUnique', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
          ignore: '<',
          ngModel: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, ele, attrs, c) {
        attrs.$observe('isUnique', function(postToUrl) {
          console.log('Ignore value: ' + scope.ignore);
          console.log('Model has value: ' + scope.ngModel);
          console.log('Url to Post ' + postToUrl);
        });
      }
    }
}]);
```

and using it like this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" ignore="::name" is-unique="/to/some/url?name={{name}}" />
```

The issue is when the application is loaded `scope.ignore` is `undefined`, but whatever I typed first thing into the text box `scope.ignore` is set to that value. I want if the `scope.ignore` has undefined value at start, it must remain `undefined`. Is there any way to fix it?

here is the plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/kAsTYiPx2AsotVbBTnNf?p=preview

Comment: Did you test it before? <input type="text" ng-model="name" data-ng-init="myvar=name" is-unique="/to/some/url?name={{name}}" />

Comment: No, I dont want to initialize it my self, values will come from db.

Comment: $scope.inputChangeController=function(str){ if (str==undefined){  $scope.name=undefined}else{$scope.name=str}} ------<input type="text" data-ng-change=inputChangeController(name)" ng-model="name" ignore="::name" is-unique="/to/some/url?name={{name}}" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that is the feature of one-time binding when using `::` that Angular will watch until the variable get's any value other than `undefined`. But if you want that behaviour, then use a local variable like this:

```
app.directive('isUnique', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
          ignore: '=',
          ngModel: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, ele, attrs, c) {
        var localIgnore = scope.ignore;

        attrs.$observe('isUnique', function(postToUrl) {
          console.log('Ignore value: ' + localIgnore);
          console.log('Model has value: ' + scope.ngModel);
          console.log('Url to Post ' + postToUrl);
        });
      }
    }
}]);
```

The second option can be to modify your code like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" ignore="{{::name}}" is-unique="/to/some/url?name={{name}}" />
```

And then remove `ignore: '=',` from your directive's scope.

```
app.directive('isUnique', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
          ngModel: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, ele, attrs, c) {
        attrs.$observe('isUnique', function(postToUrl) {
          console.log('Ignore value: ' + attrs.ignore);
          console.log('Model has value: ' + scope.ngModel);
          console.log('Url to Post ' + postToUrl);
        });
      }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: ah! Actually was using the same local variable approach earlier...but was looking for some straight out of box solution :)

Comment: an alternate approach is to intializes $scope.name='' in controller.

Comment: The second options is not correct, atts.ignore always have older value, like if you typed '123' it will have '12' bcoz its not yet calculated

Comment: Oops sorry, forgot to add `::` while copying the answer.

Comment: I think the only perfect approach is to use the first one, thx.